# Why do non-ASCII characters get mangled when my shell script is run from cron?

Tags: bash, character-encoding, cron

I've got a simple [shell script which synchronizes Google Calendars](https://github.com/nikreiman/gcal-agenda/blob/master/sync-calendars) for quick local access. When I run it from the command line, events with non-ASCII characters (like ä, ö, å) work fine, and the generated output file looks perfect.

However, when the script gets run from cron, the characters are mangled in the output files. For instance, Ä is replaced with the literal character sequence `\xc4` (ie, "Ärstidernas" becomes "\xc4rstidernas"). The script is being run on OSX 10.6. I've no idea which tool in the chain (cron, bash, python-2.6) is causing this to happen. What could be wrong?

Comment: Without seeing your crontab entry it may be difficult to diagnose your problem. By the way, why do you use `eval`? It shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: The substitution looks like something Python would do.  You probably have Årstidernas, not Ärstidernas, btw (-:

Comment: `if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]` is a Useless Use of Test.  See http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#test

Comment: @tripleee Yeah, it was my flatmate who made the event and had a typo in the name. :) Also, I prefer using Test as it improves readability.

Comment: Oh, I mean you should use `if $googleCli calendar list --cal "$calendar" --date "$today,$stopDay" > "/tmp/$calendar"; then mv ...` in the script.  I don't see how putting the exit code in a separate clause makes it more readable; quite the contrary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @aztaroth, I did a bit of research on `LC_CTYPE` and found that the correct solution is to add this to the script:

```
export LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
```

`LC_CTYPE` expects a character encoding type, not a language charset. So setting it to UTF-8 fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Add `LC_CTYPE=sv_SE` at the beginning of the crontab, maybe?